# Assigning values to a DenseTensor converted from SparseTensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a test code that can minimally explain my question:

```
import tensorflow as tf

t = tf.Variable([[1], [0], [2], [0]], tf.int32)
print(t)
tf.assign(t, [[0], [0], [0], [0]]) # this will succeed

t1 = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0], [2, 0]], values=["1", "2"],         dense_shape=[4, 1])
t2 = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(t1, default_value="0")
t3 = tf.string_to_number(t2, out_type=tf.int32)
print(t3)
tf.assign(t3, [[0], [0], [0], [0]]) # this will fail with     "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'"
```

I wonder is it because of mutability of a Tensor or other reasons?

Any way that I can directly change values in a SparseTensor with dtype=tf.string ?